Bank Vault Heist by Digging a tunnel. 80s Movie or Tv-Movie
Yup, This is either Brittsh/irish, New Zealand or Aussy movie or tv-movie from the 80s. 
So there are about 5 guys that dig a tunnel via the sewer tunnel into the bank vault. They finally get inside at Friday after closing and work all weekend stealing stuff from the deposit boxes. 
Monday morning the cops find out but by then the gang is all gone.
I remember the end of the movie where the brain of the gang is in court but bust out a window and jump down where a girl is waiting with a motorcycle.
So this is also based on a real heist..I think german or so...
WHAT's THE Dang title?

I think you're after The Great Riviera Bank Robbery (AKA Dirty Money AKA Sewers of Gold) from 1979 with Ian McShane.

Bert (McShane) and Jean (Clarke) are members of a right-wing nationalist organisation closely connected to the Organisation de l'armée secrète. [...] Needing to raise cash to buy arms, Bert, an ex-paratrooper known as 'The Brain', devises a plan to dig their way into a bank vault. Needing criminal expertise, they persuade some local French gangsters to join them, in return for a cut of the haul. [...] After several nights spent digging through a wall in a sewer, they break their way into the deposit boxes, and try to make their getaway without being caught.

McShane escapes the courthouse (or police station?) by jumping out of the window and driving away on a motorcycle in the end. It was based on a real robbery in France perpetrated by Albert Spaggiari.
